# html make 2 double-line texts have same distance between lines

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to format my layout of html into this way:
[image]

However, my actual result is this:
[image]

I want the distance between "service name"(Pirate Service) and "status"(Proposed) equal to the distance between "API Name"(Get All Loot) and "Resource Name"(Pirates), but the service-status(Pirate Service, Proposed) distance is too large.

How to reduce the distance between "Service Name"(Pirate Service) and "Status"(Proposed)?

my typescript code:

```
import "./Description.css";

interface DescriptionProps {
  name: string;
  service: string;
  resource: string;
  status: string;
}
export const Description = ({name, service, resource, status,}: DescriptionProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="name-service-container">
        <h1>
          <span className="names">{name}</span>
        </h1>
        <h4>
          <span className="services">{service}</span>
        </h4>
      </div>

      <br />

      <div className="resource-status-container">
        <p>
          <span className="resources">{resource}</span>
        </p>
        <p>
          <span className="status">{status}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
);
};
```

my css:

```
.resources {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  font-style: italic;
  clear: left;
}

.names {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

.services {
  float: right;
  bottom: 0;
}

.status{
  float: right;
  top:0;
}

.resource-status-container{
  margin-right: 30px;

}

.name-service-container{
  margin-right:30px;
}
```

Comment: Add display: flex;  to the container and the p-elements flex: 1;

Comment: @Sli4o if I add display:flex to the container, the resource and status will stick together like pirateActive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```css
h1,h4,p {
  margin:0;
}

.container {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-between;
  background-color:gray;
}

.name-service-container,
.resource-status-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:center;
  gap: 0.5rem; /* Control distance between elements */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="name-service-container">
    <h1><span class="names">{name}</span></h1>
    <h4><span class="services">{service}</span></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="resource-status-container">
    <span class="resources">{resource}</span>
    <span class="status">{status}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I was stuck at css style & layout for a while.